# Reproduce slow_query_log output for a single query without enabling slow_query_log

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

How do you reproduce the output for a single query without enabling the slow_query_log?  I'm looking for rows_examined.

Answer (score 0):

The format won't be exactly the same, but if you just want to know the `Rows_examined` for a query you can get that by running the query with [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) and looking at the `rows` count in the output.

```
mysql> explain select *
    -> from your_table
    -> where name like '%a%'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: your_table
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 131831
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is a complex query with multiple joins, how does that work?

Comment: The output of `EXPLAIN` will contain one row for each table in the query. Try it out and see for yourself. More details here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html